# Recursion in the minimax algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, minimax

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game with the [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) but I can't get my head around the recursion. How do I have it return the move sometimes, and other times the score? Every time I run it now it doesn't work because the 'value' is a tuple being compared with a float.

```
def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    # checks if game ended
    if terminal(board):
        # returns the score the game would end if you go down this path
        return utility(board)
    # returns all posible moves
    choices = actions(board)
    
    if player(board) == X:
        big = -INFINITY
        for action in choices:
            copy_board = result(board,action)
            value = minimax(copy_board)
            if value > big:
                big = value
                choice = action
    else:
        small = INFINITY
        for action in choices:
            copy_board = result(board,action)
            value = minimax(copy_board)
            if value < small:
                small = value
                choice = action
    return choice
```

Comment: Did you try returning two values: `(move, score)`?  These can default to `None` if not needed.

Comment: Wouldn't you only care about returning the move on the top-level? A common approach is to set a `best_move` variable in an enclosing scope.